# Error in python griddata: "builtins.IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, grid

### Griddata error

(adapted from: [Matplotlib contour from xyz data: griddata invalid index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781025/matplotlib-contour-from-xyz-data-griddata-invalid-index))

I have a matrix of some values corresponding to a set of coordinates. I want to load the data from an external file and use a griddata object to interpolate between the points. However when running the code i get the error:

"builtins.IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" from griddata. I have no idea what this means?

A piece of sample code:

```
def main():
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781025/matplotlib-contour-from-xyz-data-griddata-invalid-index
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml

ndata = 121
ny, nx = 100, 200
xmin, xmax = 0, 10
ymin, ymax = 0, 10

Data = np.loadtxt('Data.dat')
Data = Data.flatten(1)

x = np.array([j for i in np.arange(0,11,1) for j in np.arange(0,11,1)])
y = np.array([j for i in np.arange(0,11,1) for j in np.arange(0,11,1)])
#x = np.random.randint(xmin, xmax, ndata)
#y = np.random.randint(ymin, ymax, ndata)

xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
zi = ml.griddata(x, y, Data, xi, yi)

plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 15, linewidths = 0.5, colors = 'k')
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', c = 'b', s = 5, zorder = 10)
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.show()
```

Data.dat may be obtained from: http://pastebin.com/Uk8SHA1F

Notice how it works with the comprehensions supplying either x or y in combination with the other coordinate being the random coordinate (commented), but not when using comprehensions for both x and y?

Answer (score 3):

"builtins.IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" from griddata. I have no idea what this means?

`index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

You would get this error, when 1-D array is supplied when 2-D is expected, and the first index is out of bounds. For example:

```
>>> np.array([])[0,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

>>> np.array([2,4])[3,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Note that if you didn't specify any value for 2nd axis, you would get a different error:

```
>>> np.array([])[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index out of bounds
```