# Contour line error with plt.contour in python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am plotting a contour plot in python 3 with matplotlib, and I am getting a strange result. At first, I was using plt.contourf, and notices there was a strange north-south linear artifact in the data that I knew shouldn't be there (I used simulated data). So I changed plt.contourf to plt.contour, and the problem seems to be that some of the edge contours are deformed for some reason (see picture).

[image]

Unfortunately, it is hard for me to past a simple version of my code because this is part of a large GUI based app. Here is what I am doing though.

```
#grid the x,y,z data so it can be used in the contouring
self.beta_zi = 
#This is matplot griddata, not the scipy.interpolate.griddata
griddata(self.output_df['x'].values,self.output_df['y'].values,
                              self.output_df['Beta'].values,
                              self.cont_grid_x,
                              self.cont_grid_y,
                              interp='linear')

    #call to the contour itself
self.beta_contour=self.beta_cont_ax.contour(self.cont_grid_x,self.cont_grid_y,
                                  self.beta_zi,
                                  levels=np.linspace(start=0,stop=1, num=11, endpoint=True),
                                  cmap=cm.get_cmap(self.user_beta_cmap.get()))
```

This seems like a simple problem based on the edges. Has anyone seen this before that can help. I am use a TK backend, which works better with the tkinter based GUI I wrote.

UPDATE: I also tried changing to scipy.interpolate.griddata because matplot's griddata is deprecated, but the problem is the same and persists, so it must be with the actual contour plotting function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem had to do with how I was interpreting the inputs of contour and grid data.

```
plt.contour and matplot.griddata takes 
x = x location of sample data
y = y location of sample data
z = height or z value of sample data
xi = locations of x tick marks on grid
zi = locations of y ticks marks on grid
```

Typically xi and yi are all the locatoins of each grid node, which is what I was supplying, but in this case you only need the unqiue tick marks on each axis.

Thanks to this post I figured it out.

[Matplotlib contour from xyz data: griddata invalid index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781025/matplotlib-contour-from-xyz-data-griddata-invalid-index)